# SVG/PNG files open differently in the browser

Tags: python, image, svg, png

I am working on a project where our database is on svg format. Now, the weird thing (I don't know much about image formats) is that the image looks totally different if I open it on a computer program like Image Viewer, ImageMagick or Pinta, to how the image looks when I open it on a browser (be it Mozilla or Chrome). I am attaching an image (converted from svg to png) for convenience and you can see that the difference is really big if you open it on a browser compared to a normal program (if you download it and open it on your computer).

[image: The image]

Now, I opened it on Python to see what is going on, and apparently the image is on RBGA format. I thought to convert it to RGB, and did it using the following code:

```
img = Image.open(os.path.join(PNG_REPO, page)[:-4] + ".png")
arr = np.array(img)
rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
img = Image.fromarray(rgbImage)
img.save("please.png")
```

and then, weird stuff happened. The image seems to have become completely black (attached below) and opening it on Python, a local program or a browser doesn't make any difference anymore.

[image]

Anyone has any idea what is going on? I think that I am losing it and I am completely stucked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, SVG and PNG are totally different.

SVG (Scallable vector graphics) is not a standard image format : the image is not stored as an raay of pixel (or derivative), but as a vectorized format. To display it, you would have to render the vectors into pixels, then display them. The big assets of this approach are the quality vs. size : for illustrations, you can have a fantastic quality for almost nothing in size, however, it requires more time to process, and the decoding is very different from other image formats, thus it is often not supported by image viewers, and the renders can depend a bit on the renderer.

PNG (Portable network graphics) on the other hand is still based on pixel, and is very widely supported.

As for your question, your image have an alpha (transparency) channel. When converting it to RGB, you are getting rid of this transparency, which opencv translates into a fixed color. Here, this color is (0,0,0), that is to say black.

You should try this :

```
img = Image.open(os.path.join(PNG_REPO, page)[:-4] + ".png")
img.load()
new_img = Image.new("RGB", img.size, (255, 255, 255))
new_img.paste(img, mask=img.split()[3]) # 3 is the alpha channel
new_img.save("should_be_good.png")
```

Comment: And indeed, it is good. (of course instead of png in the third and fourth line, it should be img).

I know that SVG and PNG are totally different formats, but I thought that converting from one to other (I used cairosvg) is fine. And well, if I do that and then proceed with your code, then the PNG file looks very similar to the SVG one.

Comment: I fixed my code, sorry about that ! Good to know that helped. Your conversion seemed to be good, it's just that openCV handles transparency quite badly (by that I mean that it does not leave you the choice to have a different background color)

Comment: Thank you! I spent two hours trying to do this.

On a related note, do you know what would be the easiest way of removing the header and the footer from the musical sheer?